# Laravel - could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

Tags: php, laravel, database, sqlite

**UPDATE:**
I figured out what's going out, The PHP server that I use run my electron app seems not loading pdo_sqlite extension while the global php executable on my system works when I execute "php artisan migrate" from the command line. So that there is a mismatch with those two PHP versions.

 
I ran into a strange issue after switching to my new device. The artisan command migrate is working but when I try to access a page that connect to the database I got this error
"could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)"
My configuration are as shown below
Laravel 8.40
PHP 7.3 with enabled extensions

- pdo_sqlite
- sqlite3
- pdo_mysql

Comment: what database are you actually using? Sqlite?

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, And It was working normally on my old laptop, idk the strange when I try to migrate the db no problems occurs

Comment: In addition to checking what extension you have installed in the command line, try adding `phpinfo()` in one of your route handlers to check that you have the same expected extensions in the PHP web handler

Comment: @apokryfos Here is a list of the enabled extensions using "get_loaded_extensions()" method. [link](https://i.imgur.com/l5mqS9b.png)

Comment: @apokryfos Oh the pdo_sqlite extension seems missed despite that I uncommented it in php.ini file.

Comment: @apokryfos I appreciate your attention. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).